# JQuery Multistep Progress-Bar: next_fs Problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-progressbar

we use a multi-step form with a progressbar. For some reason, the progressbar doesn't add the class="active" to the 2nd step after the first button click, but jumps right to step 5.

Can you see my error?

```
$(".next").click(function() {
  if (animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
```

The page this is used: https://quiz.purevisionmethod.com/app/blurry-vision/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Shouldn't really help you as you should include *all* the details in the question, not in a *transient* website - but you have multiple (probably 4..) fieldsets before the ones that contain the next buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The problem is that when I try to paste the relevant form code, I get an error message that it's too much code in the question area... 

I have this though within the 2nd Fieldset:

`<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/> `

That should work, no?

Comment: Well, you wouldn't paste your entire website, just enough to *reproduce* the problem - in your case you'd probably not include the extra fieldsets as you weren't aware they were the problem then not be able to create a snippet that *reproduces* the problem - leading you to investigate further and find the problem yourself.  Have a read of [mcve]

Comment: The problem is `$("fieldset").index(next_fs)` which looks at all of the fieldsets to get the index - changing the button won't make any difference